# how to get and show all content of BD using cURL?

Tags: curl

I'm new on the issue of the use of curl.

The problem is when I am using a command like this:
[1](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image665179.png) curl --request GET http:// localhost:9200/workgroups/group/_search?pretty=true

I get only 10 random items out of a total count. 
(in [my example](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image665179.png)  - 22 items)

The question is how to change this number? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

curl --request GET "http:// localhost:9200/workgroups/_search?pretty=true&size=BIGNUMBER"

BIGNUMBER is set by yourself.